# Top 10 technologies for _fast_ enterprise-level web development

Tags: content-management-system

Imagine I need to develop a project similar to TripAdvisor. Apache and PHP is so old days - it will take ages to create it, I will have to care about many things from design to security etc, it will not be maintainable etc. I cannot use one of CMS since they seem to be not flexible enough for my needs. So, what technologies would help me?

Comment: Firstly, what is your current skillset and what is the timeframe? Without knowing those, it would be pretty much useless giving relevant advice.

Comment: C++/Java/C#. Timeframe is the quicker the better but without compromising on quality and flexibility

Comment: Fast and enterprise-level do not go in the same sentence.  Take any big corporate website, from TripAdvisor to Google to Amazon - all of these companies have hundreds or thousands of people actively developing their website every day, with even more non-technical support staff doing other work, and it's still taken them years and years to get to where they are now.  Don't kid yourself, you can't just churn out a competitor in a few nights, no matter what server stack or framework you use.

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks! Pick a language, pick a Framework. Rails, Django, web2py etc...

Comment: Thank you. Could you recommend any article on which one to choose. Are there any frameworks which are for Java or C# as opposed to scripting languages?

Comment: frameworks spouted in scripting languages because of their emphasis on RAD (Rapid Application Development). If you want to write your application fast then I'd suggest you use a dynamic language. However, IIRC there are frameworks for Java and C# too, but I couldn't give you any specifics.